# Special chars \n and \r on Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm developing an Android 2.2 aplication.

I use SQlite3 to store some text that would be displayed inside a TextView.

I want to add some new line and carriage return to that text, but I don't know if I can use '\n' and '\r' inside SQlite3.

Any advice?

Comment: I don't know SQlite at all, but usually the database stores the actual characters and the conversion of `\n` or `\r` happens at compile time when using string literals.  So what to use would depend on your language and compiler, not your datastore.

Comment: @Kendrick: so, I can use it, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the SQLite API properly, and using bind parameters rather than dynamically generating SQL, you can use these characters without problems.

The database likely just encodes the characters into chunks of bytes given some character encoding anyway, so the fact that `00001010` means "newline" in some contexts when decoded with most character sets is wholly irrelevant.  It goes into the text column just like everything else.

Now if you're not using prepared statements but instead are generatic SQL programmatically, you might run into issues depending on how SQLite handles embedded line breaks within string literals (it may or may not handle this fine).  But this shouldn't be a problem, because you can work around this anyway (even if you *need* to dynamically generate your statements, just generate a statement with `?` placeholders in, prepare it, then bind your variables).

Comment: +1 Binding params with statements is the way to go. That should handle lower level details (such as this) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to escape them? `\\n`, `\\r`